# Difference between the Apache Storm and LMAX Disruptor

Tags: apache-storm, disruptor-pattern

What are the contrasting differences between the Apache Storm and LMAX Disruptor? Are both solving different problems all together? If so, what are they? I was learning the `Apache Storm` for couple of days, and I see some similarities with the LMAX Disruptor. Though the LMAX Disruptor is used to pass messages between the threads, the events that do some process on the data are chained together (like a tree, a diamond, a triangle, a simple sequence). Similarly the Storm's `Spouts` are chained with multiple `Bolts` that performs some process on the data, the data passing from one Bolt to the other till there are no more Bolts. Is this not similar to the LMAX Disruptor or do I see it wrongly? Apart from this, can the Apache Storm too can perform faster on huge volume of data like LMAX Disruptor?

Answer (score 4):

The Disruptor is high performance data structure for passing messages between **threads**.

Apache Storm is intended for passing messages between **process** (probably on different physical machines).

They are trying to solve fundamentally different problems, inter thread messaging -v- inter process messaging.

Comment: This is incorrect as Storm uses Disruptor for intra-worker communication

Comment: I think my answer still stands. Even if Storm utilises the disruptor to achieve its goals they are targeting different problem spaces and thus target their API's accordingly. There is nothing in the disruptor implementation for dealing with networks, it is purely about inter thread message passing.

Comment: What you say in the comment is true but the following is a best misleading:
"Apache Storm is intended for passing messages between process (probably on different physical machines)."
That is just part of what it does, the other part in fact *does* use Disruptor.
http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/

Answer (score 2):

You can say storm is simplified High level API which uses LMAX disruptor internally with additional good features like guaranteed message processing, acking, failure handling(machine level, worker level), easy to use distributed computation.

Answer (score 1):

Storm utilizes disruptor 
http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/

more here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disruptor_%28software_pattern%29